# how to connect source files and header files in vscode in C

Tags: c, header-files

I received 3 files from my teacher, main.c , something.c , something.h .

the header file contains the declarations of the functions.
something.c contains the functions.
main.c contains several calls to the functions.

my question is, how can i run main.c and have everything connected? in python i just import the module and im done (as long the file im importing is saved at the system variables directory or same directory).

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile both something.c and main.c and link them together in one binary executable file. I don't know which OS are you supposed to run this on, if using Ubuntu, or any linux for that matter you could install gcc or clang to compile your code.

For example:

```
clang -c something.c main.c
clang something.o main.o
./a.out
```

First line compiles your files individually (creating main.o and something.o files) Second line links them together creating one executable file (a.out) Third line runs the executable file.

Comment: You can compile and link the files in one step: `clang something.c main.c -o ./a.out`. Of course `main.c` has to `#include` the header file (`something.h`) with the prototypes of the functions in `something.c`.

Comment: one more question, why do i even need to declare the functions in the header file then? if i compile them together, wouldn't they "link" ?

Comment: actually one more question, where do i need to save the files? all in the same directory?

Comment: @DarkLeader in real life project you're more likely to have compilation and linkage as separate steps, and each source file will be compiled separately only when the object files does not exist yet or is older than the source file (`make` or any other build tool allows detecting that to save the build time).

Comment: You need to declare the functions in the header file so the file main.cpp can be compiled independently of the something.c. By including something.h with the function declarations you are making a promise that the definition of those functions will be available after the link process.

Comment: Yes, save them all in the same directory. Your executable file will also be created in that build directory. As @bereal mentioned, you would probably need to use make or some other build tool in the future, but this is fine for the first step.

Comment: @Meliodas even the header file? all 3 in the same directory? I currently saved it in my minGW folder in the "include" folder. guess i'll change it. thank you guys!

Comment: @DarkLeader That depends on the #include statement in your .c files. If it says #include "something.h" it expects something.h to be in the same directory. For example if you create a subdirectory called "headers" and move the header file inside, the include statement would have to be #include "headers/something.h." Try these out a bit.

Comment: @Meliodas then why does the "math.h" file for example is saved in the "include" folder in minGW? I'm just trying to find a pattern here.

Comment: @DarkLeader "By default, the preprocessor looks for header files included by the quote form of the directive #include "file" first relative to the directory of the current file, and then in a preconfigured list of standard system directories. 
For the angle-bracket form #include <file>, the preprocessor’s default behavior is to look only in the standard system directories.

On a normal Unix system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers requested with #include <file> in: /usr/local/include,libdir/gcc/target/version/include,/usr/target/include,/usr/include"

Comment: @DarkLeader In theory you could place your header files in these predefined system directories, but you should never do so. Those folders should be reserved for system libraries, which are included in the angle-bracket form #include <file>. Also, in real life projects you would use version control system (like git), and it is convenient that all the code you write is in the same directory, but divided into multiple subdirectories to have a better organization.